# Double input is mixing the results // save data

Tags: c#

It's the following
I have a combobox being used as dropdown list
Problem:
I have to input data on the combobox in two ways (directly and via xml table load), and they both work out different.
For example:

the direct way:

```
  private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (comboBox4.SelectedItem == "Metal")
        {   
           checkBox1.Checked = true;
           int variableofmetal = 1; //there are various types of metal that open up to choose, and by default i choose the first one, therefore 1.
        }
     }
```

but the user then wants the 3rd kind of metal, and so,     ´variableofmetal = 3;´ and checkBox3.Checked = true; and also checkBox1.Checked = false;     now.

then the user saves the data, and the variableofmetal = 3 is properly saved in a .xml file.
when the user loads the .xml file back, there will be a problem right there.
Because all the dropdown list is under comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged, it will revert checkBox1 to checked again, and the checkBox3 will not be checked as the user saved.

Any solution suggestion? (noob here)

Comment: Load the xml in `FormLoad` event, and check the appropriate checkboxes to true/ false ?

Comment: I'm doing that already, theres a switch that does the following: switch(variableofmetal) case1: checkBox1.Checked = true. The problem is that the combobox tramples the loading of the xml file, because it comes after it

Comment: Why is that? Are you setting `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` somewhere?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the markup, please?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that is not a option, because i want the user to load the xml when he wants to